How to identity part?
I am trying to repair a motor controller. I have another good one I am using as a reference as shown below. I am trying to identify these "GTI" and "GUI" surface mount components so I can replace them on my bad board where these had blow up during a power spike.
Of course any searches for "GUI" lead to graphical user interface and "GTI" leads to the car.
Any suggestions on how I can identify these components? Thanks!



The one marked GT1 is a ROHM BCX17 PNP transistor.

The one marked GU1 is a ROHM BCX19 NPN transistor.

The marking style on newer ROHM parts changed, but here is a picture of the   SSTA06T116 that still shows the old marking style that is used on the parts in question (the marking code is R1G):

(Source: lcsc.com)
My tip for finding parts is: make sure you're searching the correct markings. Like in this case, it's easy to mix up 1 and I or 0 and O. Try to vary your search if aren't successful at first.
